# Performance issues using ASP.NET MVC5 (OrchardCMS 1.9.1) with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

**Solution**

Solved this by doing some customization for the Navigations. Our navigation has hundreds of links that too using "ContentMenuItem". The lazy lookup for each item and on top of that our custom view generation was making it hell slow.
We took things to client side (using ajax requests) and only a very small footprint of the navigation gets loaded on page load. Which solved the whole problem.

**Question**

We have gotten into a very strange performance issue. We are using Orchard CMS 1.9.1 which is the latest available from orchardproject.net

We have two environments Stage and QA. We created the database for QA as a clone of the Stage DB around 2 weeks ago. The codebase for both applications is absolutely same.

The response time for Stage application is very bad. A page with nothing except the navigations is taking approx 3 to 4 seconds on QA platform and on Staging the 100% replica of that page is taking around 20 seconds.

We had these hosted on Azure and we see the same behavior once we export it and import it locally. With NewRelic analytics we see that the Database queries are taking aaprox. two to three times more time on Stage DB than on QA.

We tried switching the DBs for both applications and we get the same result which gives some some clue that it has something to do with the Database.

We tried looking into SQL profiling but we couldn't get any useful insight out of it as it involves hundreds of underlying Nhibernate queries which makes it very difficult to analyze what is going on.

Please guide what we should look into.

Many Thanks

Comment: have you tried this one: https://orchardprofiler.codeplex.com/

Comment: Yes, it's absolutely impossible to guess what's going on there without analyzing a profile, so you should do that. By the way, even 3-4 seconds is really bad, so there's a problem even on your QA setup.

Comment: We installed orchardprofiler and here is the result of Stage: http://edwardsstage.azurewebsites.net/mini-profiler-resources/results?id=cfac4fa9-4e6e-41f1-affd-b07a34a4551d  In the results one MenuWidgetPart (228) which is making 45 SQL queries in 1556ms is taking 400ms on QA. I totally agree that even QA response is very bad. We saw avg fragmentation in some tables above 50 and tried looking in SQL Maintenance Plans with Rebuild, ReAdjust Index and Readjust Stats Tasks but it didn't help. We are not DB experts so we don't have more clues on what to do further and what might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Orchard navigation works very slow for large menus. It's "normal" navigation working. Try to use caching for menu. Example MainBit.Navigation module from Orchard Gallery https://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.MainBit.Navigation

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We ended up doing the same thing but using our custom solution.